# Using metadata class to override EF field names in MVC view model not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing an MVC5/EF6 web site, and I'm trying to keep the separation of data model and view models as complete as possible.

So my EF classes (stored in a separate assembly) looks like this:

```
public class WorksOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
}
```

I have a metadata class in my view assembly (where the view controllers live) where I override the display name and add error messages

```
public class WorksOrder
{
    [Display(Name = "Created by")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "created by cannot be blank")]
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
}
```

I attach the two classes in my view model with:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
    new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(EF.Models.WorksOrder),
    typeof(ViewMetadata.WorksOrder)), typeof(EF.Models.WorksOrder));
```

When I display the form, the field label is "CreatedById" rather than the display attribute ("Created by") specified in the metadata class.   I know the AddProviderTransparent has worked because if I try to submit a form with the CreatedById field empty, I get the error message ("created by cannot be blank").

**Edit**: This is the Razor file (I've cleaned out the unimportant stuff (divs etc).

```
@model App.Models.WorksOrderCreateModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorksOrder.CreatedById, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WorksOrder.CreatedById, new { @class = "form-control col-md-3" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorksOrder.CreatedById)
```

Comment: Can you share you View code which uses ViewModel field to generate label text?

Comment: @Lanorkin I've added the razor view code

Comment: Is it possible that validation is allowed to be overridden, whereas DisplayName isn't?

Answer (score 5):

In MetaData class Create a Partial Class something like this.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(WorksOrderMetaData))]
public partial class WorksOrder
{
}

public class WorksOrderMetaData
{
    [Display(Name = "Created by")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "created by cannot be blank")]
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
}
```

This will work

Comment: Surely, the point of separating the view (metadata) from the dataset is so the dataset doesn't need to know the view!  Also, it wouldn't work if the dataset is in a different assembly (without circular references).  Anyway, I'll try it and report back.

Comment: This works great if everything is in the same assembly. Also good because if you regen your model from the DB, you don't lose any of your metadata.